# Insert non-printed new lines for a long (JSON) string in editor and give it out with printf (without new lines)

Tags: c

I have a long JSON-string and I want to split its logical sections in the editor with new lines. These new lines should get ignored for the output.
Unfortunately "\" (if I remember right) is compiling but leads to altered output (I think it was void spaces).

```
hal.console->printf("{\"type\":\"pid_cnf\",\"pit_rkp\":%.2f,\"pit_rki\":%.2f,\"pit_rimax\":%.2f,\"rol_rkp\":%.2f,\"rol_rki\":%.2f,\"rol_rimax\":%.2f,\"yaw_rkp\":%.2f,\"yaw_rki\":%.2f,\"yaw_rimax\":%.2f,\"thr_rkp\":%.2f,\"thr_rki\":%.2f,\"thr_rimax\":%.2f,\"acc_rkp\":%.2f,\"acc_rki\":%.2f,\"acc_rimax\":%.2f,\"pit_skp\":%.2f,\"rol_skp\":%.2f,\"yaw_skp\":%.2f,\"thr_skp\":%.2f,\"acc_skp\":%.2f}\n",
  (double)pit_rkp, (double)pit_rki, (double)pit_rimax,
  (double)rol_rkp, (double)rol_rki, (double)rol_rimax,
  (double)yaw_rkp, (double)yaw_rki, (double)yaw_rimax,
  (double)thr_rkp, (double)thr_rki, (double)thr_rimax,
  (double)acc_rkp, (double)acc_rki, (double)acc_rimax,
  (double)pit_skp, (double)rol_skp, (double)yaw_skp), (double)thr_skp), (double)acc_skp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to split the format string over multiple lines in the source, your compiler will concatenate adjacent string literals:

```
hal.console->printf(
  "{\"type\":\"pid_cnf\",\"pit_rkp\":%.2f,\"pit_rki\":%.2f,\"pit_rimax\":%.2f,"
  "\"rol_rkp\":%.2f,\"rol_rki\":%.2f,\"rol_rimax\":%.2f,"
  "\"yaw_rkp\":%.2f,\"yaw_rki\":%.2f,\"yaw_rimax\":%.2f,"
  "\"thr_rkp\":%.2f,\"thr_rki\":%.2f,\"thr_rimax\":%.2f,"
  "\"acc_rkp\":%.2f,\"acc_rki\":%.2f,\"acc_rimax\":%.2f,"
  "\"pit_skp\":%.2f,\"rol_skp\":%.2f,\"yaw_skp\":%.2f,\"thr_skp\":%.2f,\"acc_skp\":%.2f}\n",
  (double)pit_rkp, (double)pit_rki, (double)pit_rimax,
  (double)rol_rkp, (double)rol_rki, (double)rol_rimax,
  (double)yaw_rkp, (double)yaw_rki, (double)yaw_rimax,
  (double)thr_rkp, (double)thr_rki, (double)thr_rimax,
  (double)acc_rkp, (double)acc_rki, (double)acc_rimax,
  (double)pit_skp, (double)rol_skp, (double)yaw_skp), (double)thr_skp), (double)acc_skp);
```